# Handle subdomains with Yii2 (LAMP)

Tags: yii2, apache2, subdomain

I'm developing using php and Yii2, apache2 and ubuntu.

So we have domain such as domain.com (as an example). Now I need create some pages as page1.domain.com as landings, but they will be created automatically?

How should I setup vhost for this one? I don't know what subdomain name will be (can be any a-Z0-9). Should I create new vhost and enable it or I can somehow enable it on existing one?

Next problem is URL on `page1.domain.com` When we open page1.domain.com all links are like "http://page1.domain.com/xxx" but I need "http://domain.com/xxx"

So main thing is to change base url no matter what domain but reacts on it's subdomain if exist.

Answer (score 0):

Two things there:

1) **Active subdomain wildcard**

In your vhosts config file, add:

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

Then you have to add an entry in your DNS. For localhost, you can't add it directly in your hosts file:

https://serverfault.com/questions/319518/add-wildcard-subdomains-to-localhost-with-apache

2) **Create the rules**

You could add a pattern in your url manager to match the subdomains to a controller handler.

```
'http://(\d+).domain.com/' => 'controller/index',
```

*More info:*

[1] http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#rules-with-server-names

[2] http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

Comment: Is there any solution for some kind of `http://(\d+).***com/' => 'controller/index`, domain can be dynamic (not static). Code use in several sites.

Comment: For this case, you have the aliases. @web is the base URL for your app, but I never tested in url rules. info: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html